# Timestamp Issue: Python doesn't recognize Timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, strptime

so I am pretty new to coding, but seriously I do not see where I am heading wrong with my code.

So what I want to do is an operation where I subtract 365 days from a specific day. Thats the easy part. But when I start to import my array with all the timestamps - it doesn't recognize them. Funnily if I just type in the timestamp by hand, it does!!

What I wrote looks like this:

```
r= '2016-12-22 00:00:00'
u = datetime.strptime(r,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d = timedelta(days=365)
print (u-d)
```

The result:

```
2015-12-23 00:00:00
```

But when I use an indexing command such as:

```
r= p_dates[254]
```

which is EXACTLY the same as:

```
print(p_dates[254])
2016-12-22 00:00:00
```

It returns an Error:

**strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp**

Seriously - what the heck is happening :D Would be glad, if somebody can help a noob out.

Thanks in advance and happy holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that the first argument needs to be of str type. You can check the `type` of any variable like `type(variable)`. Here just cast to a string from a timestamp

```
u = datetime.strptime(str(r),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```